# Function template and private copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to implement the following compare function template :

```
template<typename T>
int     compare(T x, T y)
{
  if (x > y)
   return 1;
  else if (x < y)
   return -1;
  else
   return 0;
}
```

It works for every classic type but the following class won't work :

```
class c
{
private:
  c &operator=(const c&) {return *this;}
  c(const c &){}
public:
  bool operator==(const c&) const {return true;}
  bool operator>(const c&) const {return false;}
  bool operator<(const c&) const {return false;}
  c(){}
};
```

When I try to compare two instances of my class, the compiler yells that he can't because the copy ctor is private, I tried to pass references to my function template instead but it didn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Pass const references.

Comment: What exactly did you try about references, and *how* did it not work?

Comment: Copies uncopyable objects. Asks why the compiler "yells" about the copy constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the template take references:

```
template<typename T>
int     compare(const T& x, const T& y)
```

This way, no copies are involved.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to pass the const with my reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing by values which requires copy of the parameter to be created. That is why it needs to create copy and hence it requires copy constructor. Passing by reference or pointer will help here.

```
template<typename T>
int     compare(const T& x, const T& y)
```

or

```
template<typename T>
int     compare(const T* x, const T* y)
```

Answer (score 0):

your template is for objects passed by value and the copy Ctor in your class expects object references; The compiler will try to use a default Ctor and since it does not find one it screams for help.

Solution:

```
either define the template so that it accepts object references (as already suggested)
or
define the copy constructor
```